# How to get the key-text from the virtual key code?

Tags: c++, winapi

How to get the key-text from the virtual key code ?

```
 KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT * kbhook = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *) lParam;
  cout << kbhook->vkCode <<endl;
```

For example the virtual key code for `q` comes to be 81. I want to return `q`. How do i do that ?

[Using UnicodeEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309132/how-to-convert-virtual-key-code-to-character-code) How do i do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert virtual key code to character code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309132/how-to-convert-virtual-key-code-to-character-code)

Comment: The answer is right there in the link you posted yourself... Just use `ToUnicodeEx` and google for examples to get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading [ToUnicodeEx documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646322%28VS.85%29.aspx), I'd try with something like this:

```
wchar_t buff[10];

BYTE keyState[256] = {0};

int result = ToUnicodeEx(
    kbhook->vkCode,
    kbhook->scanCode,
    keyState,
    buff,
    _countof(buff),
    0,
    NULL);
```

On success, `buff` should contain the Unicode character(s).

Comment: i get [this type of output](http://i48.tinypic.com/357frky.jpg) for [this](http://i49.tinypic.com/35kkbo6.jpg)

Comment: @grassPro: Don't write a `wchar_t[]` to `cout`. You need `wcout` for `wchar_t[]`.

Comment: aah..that was a mistake ! But the program can't differentiate between capital letters and small letters,can't tell about special character,can't tell if shift was pressed etc.. What is the way to do that ??

Comment: @grassPro: You may want to play with the `keyState` array (and use `LoadKeyboardLayout` function). Maybe it is possible to set shift key press state, etc. in that array.

Comment: and what is the reason you have kept the size of `buff` = 10 ? and what does `{0}` denote ?

Comment: I thought 10 was big enough size; the `={0}` syntax initializes the array with zeros. I'm not familiar with that API; I just read the doc, and tried to write some code accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

```
cout << char(kbhook->vkCode) << endl;
```